# Determine the location of cross-references

Tags: cross-referencing, zref

I'm trying to determine which cross-references land far away from their label/anchor or more generally the location of cross-references throughout a document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
A cross-reference to \Vref{fig:1} and to \Cref{fig:2}

\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure\label{fig:1}}
\vspace{50pt}
\end{figure}

\section{Some other section}
Another cross-reference to \Vref{fig:1}.

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\caption{Second figure\label{fig:2}}
\vspace{50pt}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm always using `\Cref` or `\Vref` so my thought was to patch `\@cref` and record the position using `\zsavepos`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{crefa}
\pretocmd{\@cref}{\stepcounter{crefa}\label{crefa@@@#2@@@\thecrefa}\zsavepos{crefa@@@#2@@@\thecrefa}}{}
\makeatother
```

But this leaves a space after every figure (*i.e.* the first cross-reference is `(Figure 1 )` instead of `(Figure 1)`. It so happened that using `\apptocmd` helped in this case, but is there a simpler solution?

Comment: `\stepcounter{crefa}\label` is pretty useless. You need `\refstepcounter{crefa}\label...`

Comment: After investigating I found that omitting `cleveref` for example will produce a weird extra space **before**, i.e.  `(<space>Figure 1)` instead of `(Figure 1)`. Since `cleveref` redefines the `\v....` macros from `varioref` this is an unhealthy interference